# C++ polynomials: indefinite integrals

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to find the indefinite integral of a polynomial, however neither my maths nor my coding is great. My code compiles but I believe I have the wrong formula:

```
Polynomial  Polynomial :: indefiniteIntegral() const
{
    Polynomial Result;
    Result.fDegree = fDegree + 1;
    for ( int i = fDegree; i > 0 ; i--){
        Result.fCoeffs[i] = pow(fCoeffs[i], (Result.fDegree)) / (Result.fDegree);
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Is `fCoeffs` a normal array (in which case it should be zero-indexed, while you appear to be 1-indexing it)?

Comment: \int a x^n dx = a/(n+1) x^{n+1} + C

Comment: Also you probably want to set `Result.fCoeffs[i]` based on `this->fCoeffs[i - 1]` (assuming lower array indices are lower-order coefficients). Conceptually the coefficients are shifting over. And I don't think you want `pow()` do you? Each coefficient of the integral is simply the original coefficient of the lower-order term divided by the order of the coefficient, right?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you want is

```
for ( int i = fDegree; i > 0; --i ) {
  Result.fCoeffs[i]  = fCoeffs[i-1] / static_cast<float>(i);
}
```

I don't know the underlying implementation of your class, so I don't know how you're implementing fCoeffs (if its doubles or floats) and if you need to worry about `i` being out of bounds. If its a vector then it definitely needs to be initialized to the right size; if its a map, then you may not need to.

Comment: I don't think the explicit cast is necessary, since `i` will be automatically promoted assuming `fCoeffs` is a container/array of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
Polynomial  Polynomial::indefiniteIntegral() const 
{
  Polynomial Result;
  Result.fDegree = fDegree + 1;
  for (int i = fDegree; i > 0 ; i--) {
    Result.fCoeffs[i] = fCoeffs[i-1] / i;
  }
  Result.rCoeffs[0] = 0;
  return Result;
}
```

Each monomial *a x^i* is stored as value *a* in *fCoeffs[i]*, after integration it should be moved to *fCoeffs[i+1]*, multiplied with *1/(i+1)*. The lowest coefficient is set to *0*. 
And yes, you better make sure there is room for the highest coefficient.

Example: *[1 1]* is *1 + x* and should become *C + x + 1/2 x^2* which is represented by *[0 1 0.5]*, keeping in mind that we introduced an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Actually, it should be: `Result.rCoeffs[0] = C` because this is an indefinite integral. The `C` could be given as argument to `indefiniteIntegral`, unless `fCoeffs` is of a type that knows about the concept *unspecified constant*.

Comment: This will be wildly inefficient for cases like p(x) = 1 + x^1000.  Better to have a Monomial class and give Polynomial a collection of Monomials.

Comment: It depends on how the result is interpreted. I just guessed he keeps the arbitrary constant in mind.

Comment: Hey we have no clue if that is just homework or the seed of a computer algebra system. :-)